# Блокирующие VS неблокирующие списки

Tags: unix, redis, очередь

Всем привет. Изучаю Redis, наткнулся на то, что есть просто очереди/стеки через **rpush/rpop lpush/lpop**, а есть их блокирующие версии: **brpop/brpush brpoplpush**. 
Обьясните пожалуйста, в чём разница, где можно применить блокирующие версии, и(лично пойду помолюсь), если есть теория, которая показывает, зачем такие механизмы нужны, и как они крутятся под капотом (в моём случае капомот *nix систем)

** UPD пока что, я понял что

1.Блокирующие списки задаются на определенное время и полностью блокируют вызываемый процесс (полагаю, что это удобно будет для демонов ==> запустил процесс, редис-кли поставил такое-то время жизни, и этот процесс не может делать больше ничего кроме как ждать(защита от дурака) )

2. Они используются, если мне нужно дождатся ответ от процесса, который может идти ну оооочень долго

НО, тогда вопрос вот такой: в книге "7 баз данных за 7 недель" приводится пример блок списка как части онлайн чата. Насколько вообще правильно в таком случае использовать этот механизм для чата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не до конца понятен смысл вопроса. Стандартная семантика же.

При использовании `rpop`, если в очереди нет данных, а нам они нужны, мы будем вынуждены применить поллинг - постоянно опрашивать.

При использовании `brpop` поллинг не нужен - мы автоматически получим данные, как только они появятся.

Comment: Александр, правильно ли я вас понял, что у меня например есть демон, который слушает редис. Для ефективного использования блокировочных списков, я внутри демона буду ставить прослушку для данного листа, и в случае, если данные придут, то я их получу, обработаю что мне там нужно, и обратно сделаю операцию на прослушку листа, примерно вот так: while(true) { $currentWork=$this->brpop('list',1200); if($currentWork) { // делаю операцию}   }  Так на практике это должно работать?

Comment: @AlexKhonko - ну, в общем, да. В официальной документации на странице [blpop](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) приведен пример event notification.